# How to use a relative executable to build a file on windows?

Tags: python, sublimetext2, build-automation

I have a pen-drive on which I have:

- Sublime Text 2 portable for Windows (both 32 & 64 bit)
- Portable Python Installation
- Some more things like Android ADT etc

Currently I have a batch file that "sets up" the environment variables for a cmd session, and I run run the files from cmd.. Now obviously this is not very desirable, or efficient.

How do I to build/run a file, say a `.py` one, within Sublime Text 2, using the python executable on the same pen-drive?

---

**UPDATE:**
A failed attempt
`F:\foo\SublimeText2_x64\Data\Packages\Build Systems\My Python.sublime-build`

```
{
    "working_dir": "$packages",
    "cmd": ["cd ..\\..\\.. && setupenv && cd $file_path &&",
            "python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "shell": true
}
```

---

Here's what I ended up with:

```
{
    "working_dir": "${packages}\\Build Systems",
    "cmd": ["build.bat", "python", "$file_path", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

`build.bat` (I intend on adding more languages to this, making it a multi-lang build file)

```
@echo off

if "%1"=="" call :usage 0 & goto end
if "%2"=="" call :usage 1 & goto end
if "%3"=="" call :usage 2 & goto end

set my_dir=%~dp0\..\..\..\..

::------------------------- Setting Up the Environment -------------------------
:: Python
SET PATH=^
%my_dir%\PortablePython2.7.5.1\App;^
%my_dir%\PortablePython2.7.5.1\App\Scripts;%PATH%

:: Git
SET PATH=%my_dir%\Git\cmd;%PATH%
::------------------------------------------------------------------------------

pushd %2 :: Goto to the directory with the file
python -u %3 & goto end


:: ----------------------------------- Usage -----------------------------------
:usage
echo Error: Need 3 arguments (got %1)
echo Usage:
echo    build.bat language file_path file
echo.
echo Arguments:
echo   language    : The language to build the file with
echo                 Supported languages - python
echo   file_path   : Path to the file
echo   file        : Name of the file (preferably with path)
goto end
::------------------------------------------------------------------------------

:end
popd
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wrong, you should create a .bat file receiving two parameters from sublime and do all the processing in the .bat file.

source for F:\foo\SublimeText2_x64\Data\Packages\Build Systems\My Python.sublime-build

```
{
"working_dir": "path\\to\\your\\batch\\file",
"cmd": ["build-py.bat", "$file_path", "$file"]
}
```

source for batch file

```
@echo off
setupenv
cd %1
python -u %2
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I really can't understand what the problem is. In the cmd property of the build file I skectched in this answer you can pass as many parameters as you want to the batch file.

Comment: I have another question: where is the language parameter coming from? I think you will need to create 5 different build files for the different languages and hardcode the specific language parameter in each of the files. For example, you will have one of the files with the cmd property set to ["build.bat", "python", "$file_path", "$file"] and another build file with the cmd property set to ["build.bat", "gcc", "$file_path", "$file"].